# dimension of a subspace spanned by two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $M$ and $ N$ be the subspaces of a vector space $V$ then prove that  $(\dim M) + (\dim N) = (\dim M+N) + (\dim M \cap N)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u_1, \ldots , u_k$ be basis of $M\cap N$,
 $v_1, \ldots v_s, u_1, \ldots , u_k$ - basis of $M$,
 $u_1, \ldots , u_k, w_1, \ldots w_t$ - basis of $N$.
It is easy to see that $v_1, \ldots v_s, u_1, \ldots , u_k, w_1, \ldots w_t $ is basis of $M+N$